# Syncing clocks on multiple Azure VMs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a requirement to write a load test measuring message transmission latencies. In order to simulate a large number of simultaneous uses without running into thread contention problem on one box, I'm spinning up multiple servers in Azure.

When I got my first results back, I was a little shocked to see that the results indicated the message was received before it was sent. I immediately realized that, while I had an implicit assumption that all the VMs would have their clocks synced to within milliseconds, that was clearly not the case.
I've spent several hours googling ways to resolve this, and I'm not getting anywhere. One thought was to have each VM query the time on a central server using NetRemoteTOD() using a technique similar to this [NetRemoteTOD](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.netremotetod), and then establish a per-machine correction factor to be added to the time measured from the local machine's clock. However when I tried to run that method, I got a error 2184, "The service has not been started" I have verified that both the RPC service and the Windows Time service are running on the both the client and target machines, and I have not been successful in finding any information indicating what other service needs to be running (or even if the error really means what it seems to mean). (I also get the same error when running between my development desktop and a server on our corporate network.  However, I can run it successfully to a PDC on the corporate network - but I can't find a PDC on Azure, since neither machine is part of a domain.)

So, does any one have either any information on what service needs to be started to get NetRemoteTOD (or the windows NET TIME command, which relies on NetRemoteTOD under the covers) working. Alternatively, does anyone have a suggestion for some other technique to get a consistent time reference across multiple VMs in Azure? (Note, I don't necessarily need their clocks synced, I just need a way to establish a consistent correction factor to reference the times to a common source.  Note also, I need sub-second accuracy - probably about 100 msec will do.) Basically, I just need a windows function or shell command that will get me the time to sub-second accuracy on a given remote server.

Thanks in advance.
PS. Azure servers are running Server 2008 R2 SP1